# Importing Excel file into Access: Trust Center settings?

Tags: excel, ms-access, import, settings

I am having issues importing an excel spreadsheet into Access. This is usually a very easy task to do but not this time.

Here what happens:

1. I open my access file (tried with both .accdb and .mdb) and select the External Data tab then press on the Excel icon to import an excel file.
2. The Get External Data window pops up. I browse to my file (tried both .xlxs and .xls), then click OK.
3. Nothing happens from here.  No error message, no second window asking for which spreadsheet I want to import . . . nothing.

I tried with totally different excel files or by creating a new blank access file. Tried saving the excel file as a .csv then importing a text file from Access. Those attempts did not work. But, I can import tables from other Access files without problems.

I searched the web and found one person which solve that same problem by enabling all macros in both the Access and Excel file. That solution did not work for me. I compared all the options within my Trust Center with the ones of teammate but that does not seem to be the problem.  Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this from time to time.  Seems random in nature, but you should be getting this behavior for any time MS Access tries to bring up an Access 'Wizard' dialog.  To remedy this, you will need to unregister, and re-register the office `AccWiz.dll` library.  Depending on what version of Office you are running, you will find the `AccWiz.dll` library in the `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Officexx\` folder

In a command terminal (cmd) navigate out to your specific folder that the newest version of the'**AccWiz.dll**' library is located:

To Unregister:

```
regsvr32 /u accwiz.dll
```

Then to Register the .dll again:

```
regsvr32 accwiz.dll
```

That should solve the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion (and sorry for the delay here: I should really consider those flu shots grrr). This computer is property of the government and as such, I am hesitant in changing the register information, even if it is to set it back to what it was originally. I may be overcautious here (or may be learning from experience).